# Pandas: filter dataframe by column of sets using multiple conditions regarding substrings

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a problem whereby I want to filter the following dataframe such that I only return the rows where we have both a pie and a non-pie item:

| ID | set |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple pie, banana loaf |
| 2 | banana pie, apple pie |
| 3 | banana loaf, apple tart |

Thus, the expected output would be:

| ID | set |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apple pie, banana loaf |

Note that every set in the set column contains exactly two items.

What I have tried so far:

```
df[(any("pie" in s for s in df['set'])) & (any("pie" not in s for s in df['set']))]
```

I expect I am doing something that is breaking Pandas dataframe filtering convention but not sure what exactly.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: my table seems to be showing up incorrectly here, despite being correctly displayed in the preview.

Comment: You just needed a space between the text and the tables :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on your `dataframe`:

```
df[df.set.apply(lambda x: len([s for s in x if "pie" in s]) == 1)]
```

Results:

```
   ID                       set
0   1  [apple pie, banana loaf]
```

Comment: This won't work if there's only `apple pie` in the set (one value)

Comment: The question mentions the following: `Note that every set in the set column contains exactly two items.`

Comment: Yes, my bad! :) Then this solution is OK.

Comment: I have already used the answer above, but this also looks to solve the problem in a similar but slightly more elegant way. nicely done and thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
#optionaly, convert the string to a list of items:
#df.set = df.set.str.split(", ")

tmp = df["set"].apply(lambda x: set("pie" in w for w in x))
print(df[tmp.str.len() == 2])  # 2 means there's at least one value with "pie" and at least one value without it
```

Prints:

```
   ID                       set
0   1  [apple pie, banana loaf]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split strings by the comma the explode them into multiple rows, check which ones contain 'pie' then groupby the index and keep only those with a single match.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3], 'set': ['apple pie, banana loaf', 'banana pie, apple pie', 'banana loaf, apple tart']})

mask = (
  df.set.str.split(',')
    .explode()
    .str.contains('pie')
    .groupby(level=0)
    .sum()
    .eq(1)
    )

df[mask]
```

Output

```
   ID                     set
0   1  apple pie, banana loaf
```